# Calling class variable with self

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-variables, class-variables

How would you I came up with this interesting (at least to me) example.

```
import numpy as np


class Something(object):
    a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)

    def do(self):
        self.a += 1
        print(self.a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    something = Something()
    print(something.__str__())
    something.do()
    something2 = Something()
    print(something2.__str__())
    something2.do()
    something3 = Something()
    print(something3.__str__())
    something3.do()
```

The above prints the following in the console:

```
$ python test.py
<__main__.Something object at 0x7f03a80e0518>
1
<__main__.Something object at 0x7f03a80cfcc0>
1
<__main__.Something object at 0x7f03a80cfcf8>
1
```

I'm a bit confused because I (wrongly) assumed the value of `a` would have increased.

I'm able to obtain the behaviour I would expect if I use the `@classmethod` decorator.

```
import numpy as np


class Something(object):
    a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)

    @classmethod
    def do(cls):
        cls.a += 1
        print(cls.a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    something = Something()
    print(something.__str__())
    something.do()
    something2 = Something()
    print(something2.__str__())
    something2.do()
    something3 = Something()
    print(something3.__str__())
    something3.do()
```

This correctly prints the following in the console.

```
python test.py
<__main__.Something object at 0x7faac77becc0>
3
<__main__.Something object at 0x7faac77becf8>
4
<__main__.Something object at 0x7faac77c3978>
5
```

Now, I'm wondering in the first example, when I'm calling `self.a`, what I'm accessing? It's not a class variable since I don't seem to be able to change its value. It's not an instance variable either, since this seems to be shared among different objects of the same class. How would you call it?

Is this a class variable that I'm using in the wrong way? I know the `cls` name if a convention, so maybe I'm truly accessing a class variable, but I'm not able to change its value because I haven't decorate the method with the `@classmethod` decorator.

Is this a sort of illegitimate use of the language? I mean something it's best practice to not do in order to avoid introduce a bug on a later stage?

Comment: Good, informative question! But could you edit the first line of your question "How would you I came up with this interesting (at least to me) example." so people could understand it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is happening is that `self.a` refers to *two* things at different times.

When no instance variable exists for a name, Python will lookup the value on the class. So the value retrieved for `self.a` will be the class variable.

But when *setting* an attribute via `self`, Python will *always* set an instance variable. So now `self.a` is a new instance variable whose value is equal to the class variable + 1. This attribute shadows the class attribute, which you can no longer access via `self` but only via the class.

(One minor point, which has nothing to do with the question: you should never access double-underscore methods directly. Instead of calling `something2.__str__()`, call `str(something2)` etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Answer by Daniel Roseman clearly explains the problem. Here are some additional points and hope it helps.
You can use type(self).a instead of self.a. Also look at the discussions
[Python: self vs type(self) and the proper use of class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923749/python-self-vs-typeself-and-the-proper-use-of-class-variables) and 
[Python: self.__class__ vs. type(self)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386166/python-self-class-vs-typeself)

```
import numpy as np


class Something(object):
    a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)

    def do(self):
        type(self).a += 1
        print(type(self).a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    something = Something()
    print(str(something ))
    something.do()
    something2 = Something()
    print(str(something2))
    something2.do()
    something3 = Something()
    print(str(something3))
    something3.do()
```